# Error invoking ds9 in xterm

Tags: package-management, xterm, xml

I tried invoking ds9 in a xterm, but the last one gave me the following message

`Error in startup script: can't find package xml
    while executing
"package require xml"
    ("x11" arm line 10)
    invoked from within
"switch $ds9(wm) {
    x11 {
        # set to absolute path so that if -cd command is used,
        # so we can still find our files
        set ds9(root) [file normalize [..."
    (file "/usr/share/saods9/library/ds9.tcl" line 178)
[1]+  Salida 1                ds9`

Someone know what is the problem and what can I do for solving it? Thank you so much!

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! I could resolve the problem a long time ago. @N0rbert

Answer (score 1):

Install the official Ubuntu ds9 (`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install saods9`).

If you are using Conda/Anaconda environment, I found your error with both Anaconda2-2019.10 and Anaconda3-2020.02. To solve it, downgrade the default ds9 v8.0 to v7.4 with the command `conda install ds9"<8"`. That worked for me (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS).

Comment: A friend of my just tried it on Ubuntu 18.04, and he needed to change to `conda install ds9"=7.4"` to make it work.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I could resolve the problem a long time ago, but your proposal sounds good! I will keep that in mind in case I need it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have to install TCL XML package with

```
sudo apt install tclxml
```

And also please note that `saods9` is [packaged](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/xenial/saods9) in all current Ubuntu versions.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I could resolve the problem a long time ago. I resolved it adding some lines to a file involving the ds9, whose name I don't remember.